# query() vs value() in XQuery SQL XML

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, xquery-sql

Which of the following is a better performing query?

```
--query a
Select *
UserDefXml.query('/Product/ProductName/text()')
From ProductsDB.dbo.ProductsTable

--query b
Select * 
UserDefXml.value('(/Product/ProductName)[1]','varchar(max)')
From ProductsDB.dbo.ProductsTable
```

What are the recommended scenarios for each of these? Are there any other ways to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: `.query()` returns an XML fragment, while `.value()` returns a single value (int, varchar, etc.) - so you're really comparing apples to ice-cream here - totally different things, totally different scenario - what do you need? XML or a scalar value?

Comment: Thank you @marc_s. In my case, they both return a ProductName which is a string. When I click the results returned by `.query()` I don't see any xml tags with it, just the product name. That's why I posted this question.

Comment: That's because of the `/text()` suffix you've added